# How to change Wordpress Gutenberg visual editor default font family

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

How can I make my website theme's font the same as Wordpress Gutenberg visual editor default font family ?

Everytime I publish a new post, my website font will default back to the theme's font.

I want to use the Visual Editor font in Wordpress. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaking, Gutenberg default font is based out of your OS. This approach to fonts is used to effectively reset browsers default styling.

```css
font-family: -apple-system,system-ui,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif
```

One of the possible approach would be using `enqueue_block_editor_assets` action hook to fire inside the editor and overwrite the `font-family` selector.

We can use `.editor-styles-wrapper` to overwrite the font-samilly and set it to whatever we want.

In the following example I chose the [Ubuntu font-family from the Google Font website](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Ubuntu).

Now of course for production use, you would base your font out of your theme's font.

```php
<?php
/**
 * Fires after block assets have been enqueued for the editing interface.
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/enqueue_block_editor_assets/
 * In the function call you supply, simply use wp_enqueue_script and wp_enqueue_style to add your functionality to the block editor.
*/
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', function() {

    /**
     * Register & Enqueue gfont_css.
     * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/
    */
    wp_enqueue_style( 'gfont_css', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@400;700&display=swap', [], wp_get_theme()->version, 'all' ); //... replace by any font, if your theme isn't using Google Font just enqueue a font font from your theme's directory instead and remove the data_gfont_css function below.

    /**
     * Add mandatory Google Font rel='preconnect' <link> and required attributes to gfont_css
     * Filters the HTML link tag of an enqueued style & add required attributes
     * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/style_loader_tag/
     */
    add_filter( 'style_loader_tag', 'data_gfont_css', 10, 3 );
    function data_gfont_css( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
        if( $handle === 'gfont_css' ) {
            $tag = str_replace(
                "<link rel='stylesheet'",
                "<link rel='preconnect' href='https://fonts.gstatic.com'>" . PHP_EOL . "<link rel='stylesheet'",
                $tag
            );
        };
        return $tag;
    };

} );

/**
 * Fires in head section for all admin pages.
 * Overwrite default Wordpress Gutenberg default font-familly.
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_head/
 */
add_action( 'admin_head', function() {

    /**
     * Get the current screen object.
     * If the screen object is the Gutenberg editor then inject our overwrite.
     * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/
     */
    if ( get_current_screen()->is_block_editor() )
        echo "<style>.editor-styles-wrapper{font-family:'Ubuntu',sans-serif!important}</style>";
} );
?>
```

---

> PHP > 7.1 required, [anonymous functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) used.